# How to set one pointer to multiply function?

Tags: go

How can I set one pointer to multiply function?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Cube struct {
    u int
}

func (h *Cube) space() int {
        return h.u * h.u * h.u
}

func main() {
        h := Cube {
                u: 10,
        }
        fmt.Println(h.space())

        h := Cube {
                u: 100,
        }
        fmt.Println(h.space())
}
```

The first request of println give back 1000, but with the second println it goes wrong telling no new variables on left side of :=
but I want the pointer to use all same just the u: to 100 change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:=` does two things, it creates a variable and assigns a value to it. You are trying to create a new variable called `h` in the second line and the compiler is telling you that it would not create a new variable.

Just replace that `:=` with `=`

Comment: Thanks that make the job!